# How to determine if this isomorphism is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I am presented with the following isomorphism:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x & y\end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this a linear transformation and why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you have a list of requirements to check. They are the how and why of showing that something is a linear transformation.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Strange question. It is just the identity mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to itself. Of course that is a linear transformation.

Comment: @Elmex80s Thinking that that's an identity mapping will get you into big trouble when coordinates (bases) change. The two spaces behave in exact reverse in response to such an event.

Comment: @Arthur Well it is just a strange mapping. He doesn't tell us from which set to which set it maps.

Comment: Maybe because it was so simple, it threw me off. I would have expected there to be more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping $T$ shows that $T(x,y)^{r} = (x, y)^{c}$, where the superscripts $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{c}$ represent the row and column vectors.

Then by definition of a linear transformation we have: $T(x, y)^{r} + T(u,w)^{r} = (x, y)^{c} + (u, w)^{c} = (x + u, y + w)^{c} = T(x+u, y + w)^{r}$.

Now, you can prove the second condition, namely: $T(\alpha x, \alpha y)^{r} = \alpha T(x, y)^{r}$.